# How to know if an object will collide with another object before adding it to the panel?

Tags: wpf, collision-detection, collision

Please see my code below.

I have an object which I haven't added to the panel in WPF - in this case a simple Canvas. When I debug the row "var A1= Poly.RenderedGeometry" the only thing I see is {}. No data at all - no pathGeometry, nothing.

Can you please explain what is wrong in my code? How can I know if the Polygon I am going to add to the canvas will not collide with other polygons?

```
// First and Second are 2 points, CreateNewTriangle adds a random point
// and creates a new triangle polygon
        var Poly = CreateNewTriangle(First, Second);

        if (G1.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            G1.Children.Add(Poly);
        }
        else
        {
         // In debug this row is empty - no actual geometry is present 
            var A1 = Poly.RenderedGeometry;

            foreach (Polygon item in G1.Children)
            {
                if (!item.Equals(Poly))
                {
                    var a2 = item.RenderedGeometry;
                    var col = A1.FillContainsWithDetail(a2);
                    if (!(col == IntersectionDetail.Empty))
                    {
                        IsAllGood = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely not getting any data in your element because the element either doesn't exist on screen, and thus hasn't had a chance to render, or the render pass hasn't occurred yet.  What you should do is force the `Measure` and `Arrange` calls, after which point you should have something populated for `RenderedGeometry`

```
var Poly = CreateNewTriangle(First, Second);
Poly.Measure(new Size(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue));
Poly.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Size(double.MaxValue, double.MaxValue)));
```

Comment: What about the size of my Mainwindow and my Canvas? Using your code I got intersect all the time. Forgot to mention that the other object are already on the panel and visible to the user...

Comment: In my example, I'm allowing the `Measure` call to be completely unbounded, which should be fine.  The problematic code is likely in the `Arrange` call, where instead of starting at the origin with a maximum size, you should provide a more accurate `Rect` with the location of your polygon.  @StackTackTack